# Vuejs Axios, When adding error to vee validate, error not showing (I explain more)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vee-validate

In my Vue project I use Vee-Validate and Axios.

I have an API call to register a user and when I email is already used, it throws an error. With axios I catch that error and want to display the error message. Very simple right. Just doing this:

```
this.loading = true;

this.$http.post('v1/auth/register', {
  first_name: this.first_name,
  last_name: this.last_name,
  email: this.email,
  phone: this.phone,
  password: this.password
}).then((response) => {
  this.registration_card = 2;
}).catch(error => {
  if (error.data.error.message === "email_already_exists") {
    let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
    input.errors.add({
      field: 'email',
      msg: 'email already in use'
    });
    // So the error is added and will be showing
    // Now disable the loading icon
    this.loading = false;
  }
});
```

So in the catch I add the error and I disable the loading icon within the button. Here is the button component:

```
<template>
  <button type="button">
    <span v-if="!loading">{{label}}</span>
    <loading v-if="loading"/>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
  import loading from 'vue-loading-spinner/src/components/Circle'

  export default {
    name: 'jellow-button',
    props: [
      'label',
      'loading'
    ],
    components: {
      loading
    }
  }
</script>
```

But right now the error message is not showing or even added to the error bag. When doing `{{this.errors}}` the array is empty. I already tackled the problem but I still want to found out why this doesn't work and why it works with my solution.

Solution in the button component

Change this:

```
<loading v-if="loading"/>
```

To this:

```
<loading v-show="loading"/>
```

Now `{{this.errors}}` does have error items and the error is displayed.

This is not really an ugly workaround for the problem so I am OK with this but I still want to know why it doesn't work with `v-if` for displaying the loading icon. What does this button have anything to do with the error bag?

Comment: show the complete code, you can paste it in gist.github.com
above code isn't complete, not easy to understand how is your implementation

Answer (score 0):

`v-show` toggles `display:none` whereas `v-if` removes the element from the DOM.

when you do run the following bit of code

```
let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
```

`$refs` would be unable to find the email element on the DOM if you were using `v-if`.

Comment: let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0]; refers to a custom input. Not to the button. The v-if happens in the button, not in the custom input.